# How To Seperate This Objects And Values From String in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c

```
[[Beverages:beverages.png], [Dairy:dairy.png], [Grab and Go:grabandgo.png], [Grocery:grocery.png], [Non Food Products:non-food.png], [Specialty Shop:specialitems.png], [Proteins:protein.png]]
```

==================================================================================

Above is String.

I want them to be separated like individual in add them in array like

```
[Beverages,Non Food Products,.....]

[grocery.png,dairy.png,.......]
```

Comment: Where did you get that string from?

Comment: Its coming from plist file and plist is coming from server @trojanfoe

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no effort on part of the asker.

Comment: So the string is within a single value of the plist file provided by the server?  Do you have any influence over the format of that plist file?

Comment: no its coming from server.@trojanfoe

Comment: @Kreiri If u have solution than u can give...Its not off-topic..

Comment: [Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Kreiri you are saying that beginners have no rights to ask ?

Comment: If the server is providing this information in a structured format (i.e. XML), why is it making it so hard to interpret?  What idiot invented the format of the plist file?  If you know him, then tell him it's crap.  You could "parse" the string, of course, but that's time consuming, error-prone, and tedious to code.

Comment: I agree with @trojanfoe = Plists have a nice structured XML format that can contain arrays and dictionaries. If at all possible, you should try and arrange for this plist to contain the data in an array in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
NSMutableArray *firstArray, *secondArray;
firstArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
secondArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSString *str=@"[[Beverages:beverages.png], [Dairy:dairy.png], [Grab and Go:grabandgo.png], [Grocery:grocery.png], [Non Food Products:non-food.png], [Specialty Shop:specialitems.png], [Proteins:protein.png]]";
NSArray *arrComa=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

for(NSString *strSub in arrComa)
{
    NSArray *arrColon=[strSub componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    NSString *firstString=[(NSString *)[arrColon objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[" withString:@""];
    NSString *secondString=[(NSString *)[arrColon objectAtIndex:1] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"]" withString:@""];
    [firstArray addObject:firstString];
    [secondArray addObject:secondString];
}
NSLog(@"%@", firstArray);
NSLog(@"%@", secondArray);
```